# 404 Page Being Shown While NextJS Page Is Rendering

Tags: next.js

I build all of my initial routes for a dynamic slug based on what I have available in my CMS at build time. Then as new CMS data is available, I will generate new pages when they are requested by the user.

I'm running into an issue where a user might hit `/posts/1`, but since `posts/1` has no CMS data, I'm rendering the 404 page using the [notFound](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching) boolean inside of `getStaticProps`. This is what I expect to happen.

Now, if I publish some data to `/posts/1` in my CMS, the next time a user hits `/posts/1`, the API data is fetched in the `getStaticProps` method, and the page begins to build. The problem is that the user is immediately redirected to the 404 page even though the `notFound` block is not hit. The [router.isFallback](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#fallback-pages) flag is also shown as false when it should be true since the page is building. Now, if this user were to refresh their page, they would see the generated page and no longer the 404 page since it is now built.

It seems like Next might route the user's request to the 404 page in the second scenario since it was previously a 404, but is there some way I can "block" the user's request or show my fallback until the page is rendered so that they don't see this 404 when the page is building? This scenario would not happen if the first user did not hit this slug before there was CMS data available.

Here's a simplified example of how I am using `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps`:

```js
export const getStaticPaths = async (ctx) => {
  const myInitialPaths = await fetch('http://my-cms-endpoint.com/initial-paths/');
  return {
    paths: [
      ...myInitialPaths
    ],
    fallback: true
  }
}

export const getStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
  const myPageData = await fetch('http://my-cms-endpoint.com/page/#id');
  
  if (myPageData) {
    return {
      props: {
        myPageData
      }
    }
  } else {
    return {
      notFound: true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Even if the path is not present initially ,after the first access  the page will be statically generated. So you might have to use revalidate option in Incremental Static Regeneration to invalidate the cache and show the updated page.

Comment: For anyone reading this issue, it's related to https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/25470. I will answer this question when it is fixed on Next's side.